# ¿Cómo cargar un archivo de texto abriendo el archivo antes que la aplicación?

Tags: c#

Si me pueden ayudar les agradezco con alguna orientación. Necesito abrir un archivo de texto en mi aplicación WindowsForms C#, pero no abriendo mi aplicación y luego seleccionando el archivo. Necesito hacerlo así como lo hace el notepad.exe, en el cual con darle doble clic al archivo de texto desde el explorador de archivos este se abre. Gracias.

Comment: Click derecho sobre el archivo, seleccionas abrir con y buscas tu programa... ahi marcas abrir esta extension siempre con este programa y eso es todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para lograr lo que pretendes debes de hacer algunos cambios en tu aplicación. En el archivo Program.cs donde se halla el punto de entrada a tu aplicación cuando se ejecuta, has de modificarlo así:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
            // Mostramos el archivo asociado a la aplicación que se pretende
            // abrir con la misma.
            MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVO: " + args[0]);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // Abrimos con el formulario principal de la aplicación:
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Observa que Main() admite parámetros. Cuando un archivo es asociado a una aplicación para su apertura y hacemos doble clic sobre el mismo, el sistema operativo lanza el ejecutable con el archivo como parámetro.

Así que habiendo hecho las modificaciones en la función Main, basta con que te sitúes con el explorador de Windows sobre el fichero que quieres abrir y pulsas botón derecho sobre el mismo y le das a abrir con... y le indicas que quieres abrirlo con tu aplicación.

Comment: Excelente ayuda amigo, me he guiado por el código de ejemplo y me ha funcionado perfectamente. Mil gracias.